# Excel iteration codinf=g

Tags: excel, vba, iteration

I am trying to iterate on excel for the blade element momentum theory, the code which I am using is the following-

```
solver reset 
    SolverOptions MaxTime:=100, _ 
    Iterations:=1000, _
    Precision:=0.000001, _
    AssumeLinear:=False, _
    StepThru:=False, _
    Estimates:=1, _
    Derivatives:=1, _
    SearchOption:=1, _
    IntTolerance:=5, _
    Scaling:=False, _
    Convergence:=0.0001, _
    AssumeNonNeg:=True

    SolverOk SetCell:="$D$32"= "$D$23", MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:="$Y$33"

    SolverSolve userFinish:=True
```

However I keep getting sub function is undefined??

Answer (score 0):

The command is `SolverReset` in one word.
And you don't need the indendation in VBA.